# How can I add a button with Tampermonkey to Facebook?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have this script:

```js
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/groups/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Add the "Approve All" button to the group header
    function addApproveAllButton() {
        var groupName = document.querySelector('[data-testid="groupsCometGroupHeaderTitle"]').innerText;
        var groupHeader = document.querySelector('[data-testid="groupsCometGroupHeaderContainer"]');
        var approveAllButton = document.createElement('button');
        approveAllButton.innerText = 'Approve All';
        approveAllButton.style.marginLeft = '10px';
        approveAllButton.onclick = approveAllPosts;
        groupHeader.appendChild(approveAllButton);
    }

    // Click all the "Approve" buttons
    function approveAllPosts() {
        var approveButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Approve post"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < approveButtons.length; i++) {
            approveButtons[i].click();
        }
    }

    // Add the "Approve All" button when the page is loaded
    window.onload = addApproveAllButton;

})();
```

It is supposed to approve the requests in one group, but the button is not visible on the page. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Try adding `console.log("01")` to your first function, and then check the console to see if `01` is anywhere in the console. If it is - your code is running on pageload, and something else is wrong. You can also modify the buttons you're creating, by adding a custom class of your own, and then querying the DOM after pageload, to see if the buttons exist at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried that, I added several console.log, its not reading any of the code, not sure is there im missing something, I added console error catcher :    function addApproveAllButton() {
        console.log('Starting addApproveAllButton function');
        var groupHeader = document.querySelector('.oajrlxb2.g5ia77u1.qu0x051f.esr5mh6w.e9989ue4.r7d6kgcz.rq0escxv.nhd2j8a9.j83agx80.p7hjln8o.kvgmc6g5.cxmmr5t8.oygrvhab.hcukyx3x.p56qjto6');
        if (!groupHeader) {
            console.error('Unable to find group header element.');
            return;
        }--nothing